# No se muestra la etiqueta de una URL con un archivo XML javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml

con el siguiente codigo JavaScripts trato de consultar una URL XML, para que me de como resultado el Status. Al correr el codigo no obtiene ningun dato, hice la prueba con otra URL ([introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment)) y si funciona.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
           <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"
      </head>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Estado:</h2>

<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">
Consultar</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "http://sffconsultadgt.azurewebsites.net/api/DGT/ConsultaRespuestaHacienda/clave?clave=50607111800310138781000100001040000000015113851137", true);
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
  {
    var doc = x.responseXML;
    // …
    var title = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(x.responseText, "text/xml");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = title;
  }
};
x.send(null);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hay algo extraño en la respuesta del servidor, el valor de `x.status` siempre devuelve `0`. Sin embargo al realizar la solicitud en el navegador, se obtienen los datos, incluso usando `curl` desde la consola (linux) la solicitud recibe respuesta. Yo tampoco entiendo que podría estar pasando. Seguiré investigando. Saludos

Comment: Exacto a mi me pasa lo mismo, agradezco su ayuda mauricio

Comment: pues estas buscando un elemento status pero en tu documento no existe.

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví el problema, el problema es el contexto del link que no lo analizaba bien el PHP. por lo cual tuve que ingresar el siguiente codigo para que lo detectara.

array('header' => 'Accept: application/xml')));
$url = 'http://sffconsultadgt.azurewebsites.net/api/DGT/ConsultaRespuestaHacienda/clave?clave=5060711180031013878100010000104000000001511385113';

$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

echo $xml->status;
?>